# yii2 GridView filtering conflict with other form in the same page

Tags: php, jquery, gridview, yii, yii2

I'm new to the `Yii` framework, and the situation confused me. I have a main form in a view that it has some validations. In addition, I have a `gridview` inside a modal in this view that it is hidden until the end user click a button in order to choose a field. The problem appeared just when the boss told me to have some search field in the modal (I decided to use filter in `gridview` for this purpose). After traces I've found that the reason was form validation of the first form when the filter method of gridview is trying to send `GET` request to the server to receive grid rows that related just with the filter parameters, But it's not working maybe the failure is about my understanding of `MVC` pattern.

Anyway this is some part of my codes:

View:

```
/* this section placed inside a modal div beside the main form*/
    echo GridView::widget([
                          'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                          'filterModel' => $searchModel,
                          'filterUrl' => Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('catm/grid'),
                          'rowOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $grid){
                            return ['onclick' => 'setText(\''. $model['name'] . '\');$(\'#myModal\').modal(\'hide\')',
                                    'style' => 'cursor: pointer',
                                ];
                          } 
                           ]);

Controller:
 public function actionCreate()
    {
        $modelCatm = new Catm();
        $modelApplication = new \app\models\Application();
        $modelBranch = new \app\models\Branch();
        $modelConfig = new \app\models\Config();
        $modelMedia = new \app\models\Media();
        $modelMessage = new \app\models\Message();
        $modelServiceConfig = new \app\models\ServiceConfig();

        $searchMdl = new BranchSearch();
        $dataPrv = $searchMdl->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        $webroot = Yii::$app->basePath;


        if ($modelCatm->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){

        //}
//print_r($_GET);
                $transaction=Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();

                try {

                       //Branch:    
                    $modelBranch->attributes = $_POST['Branch'];
                    //echo $modelBranch->attributes['name'];
                    if ($modelBranch->findBySql('select * from branch where name =\'' . $modelBranch->attributes['name'] . '\'')->count()==0) {
                    //echo 'not exists!';
                        if(!$modelBranch->save(false)) {echo 'error in model branch'; return 0;};
                    }

                    //Cashless ATM:
                    $modelCatm->attributes = $_POST['Catm'];
                    if(!$modelCatm->save(false)) {echo 'error in model catm'; return 0;};


                    //Application:
                    /*  file upload handling and saving the path to database*/
                    $modelApplication->attributes = $_POST['Application'];
                    $modelApplication->catm_id = $modelCatm->id;
                    $modelApplication->file = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('Application[file]');
                    //echo $modelApplication->file->baseName;
                    $modelApplication->validate();
                    $modelApplication->file->saveAs('uploads/application/' . $modelApplication->file->baseName . '.' . $modelApplication->file->extension);
                    $modelApplication->filepath = $webroot . '/uploads/application/' . $modelApplication->file->name;
                    if(!$modelApplication->save(false)) {echo 'error in model application'; return 0;};

                    //Media:
                    /*  file upload handling and saving the path to database*/
                    $modelMedia->attributes = $_POST['Media'];
                    $modelMedia->catm_id = $modelCatm->id;
                    $modelMedia->file = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('Media[file]');
                    //echo $modelMedia->file->baseName;
                    $modelMedia->validate();
                    $modelMedia->file->saveAs('uploads/media/' . $modelMedia->file->baseName . '.' . $modelMedia->file->extension);
                    $modelMedia->filepath = $webroot . '/uploads/media/' . $modelMedia->file->name;
                    if(!$modelMedia->save(false)) {echo 'error in model media'; return 0;};

                    //Messages:
                    $modelMessage->attributes = $_POST['Message'];
                    $modelMessage->catm_id = $modelCatm->id;
                    if(!$modelMessage->save()) {echo 'error in model message'; return 0;};

                    $transaction->commit();

                } catch (Exception $ex) {
                    $transaction->rollback();
                }

        return $this->render('view',[
            'modelCatm' => $modelCatm,
            'modelBranch' => $modelBranch,
            'modelApplication' => $modelApplication,
            'modelConfig' => $modelConfig,
            'modelMedia' => $modelMedia,
            'modelMessage' => $modelMessage,
            'modelServiceConfig' => $modelServiceConfig,
        ]);

        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'modelCatm' => $modelCatm,
                'modelBranch' => $modelBranch,
                'modelApplication' => $modelApplication,
                'modelConfig' => $modelConfig,
                'modelMedia' => $modelMedia,
                'modelMessage' => $modelMessage,
                'modelServiceConfig' => $modelServiceConfig,
                'searchModel' => $searchMdl,
                'dataProvider' => $dataPrv,

            ]);
        }
    }
```

I will update the question with more information of my code after your helpful comments if it is required.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with your understanding of MVC mate, Yii does a lot of things for you automatically but sometimes in cases like this you just need to get to do some things by hand.

Probably you need to change the form action in your controller to check if this is a form submission or a gridview navigation / filter and handle it differently. You need to check if some get params exist and bypass the form validation in that case.

Comment: let me test , but i'm not hopeful because i think that is done before the request arrives to the controller's action and as i said i wanted not to do just an ad-hoc approach and manipulate the javascript files of inner layers of framework.

Comment: you said "the reason was form validation of the first form when the filter method of gridview is trying to send GET request to the server to receive grid rows that related just with the filter parameters,". The idea is stop it before it gets to the form validation. I bet after some tests you will see that it probably gets handled with 1 line of code. In no way you should have to modify anything. Now I see other problems with your code that you will need to fix but that is besides the scope of this question.

Comment: ok, some needed fixes, after everything is ok do not show the view, redirect to another controller action that shows it. if you do this you can remove the else and just have return $this->render('create', [.... I believe your function is not working because of this.

Comment: also your validation is strange, no matter if the validation for your models works or not you show the view..... that might also be part of the problem.

Comment: $modelBranch->findBySql will never work findBySql is a static function http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#findBySql()-detail

Comment: i do not believe you should store files in the db $modelApplication->file = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('Application[file]');